# How to managed multiple emit event using socket.io in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've made a demo app to understand how socket.io 'emit' works. In client file I have defined a function that emit some value to server and this function is call in loop 5 times and server job is to return that value back to client.

My web client: client.html

```
    var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:8586', {transports: ['websocket']});
        
    function test2( dataSend ){
        console.log("FUNCTION 'test2()' loop test - > emit to SRV: " + dataSend);
        
        socket.emit('emitFromClient', dataSend);
        
        socket.on('feedback_emitFromClient', function (data) { // listen to news event raised by the server
            console.log("Received data from server: " + JSON.stringify(data)); //+ " || typeof: " + typeof data["result"]);                     
        });
    }
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        test2(i);
```

NodeJS server app: server.js

```
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const http = require('http');
 const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static('socketTest1'));

const io = require('socket.io')(server);//, { origins: '*:*'});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected!');
  
    var socketId = socket.id;
    var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;

    console.log("clientIp: " + clientIp + " || socketId: " + socketId);
    
    
     socket.on('emitFromClient', function (data) { 
        console.log("debug -  received event (emitFromClient) from client, socket id: "  + socket.id  + " || value: " + data );
        let ts = Date.now();
        console.log("debug -  send data from SRV to client ->  data: " + data);
        socket.emit('feedback_emitFromClient', { result: Math.floor(ts/1000), data: data }); // Send data to client 
     }); 

server.listen(8586, '127.0.0.1', function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8586');
});
```

In actual state I've received in console client something like that:

```
First, all emit events are done and then are displayed all data from server
  > EMIT event 1 from CLIENT, value: 1
  > EMIT event 2 from CLIENT, value: 2
  ..................................
  > EMIT event 5 from CLIENT, value: 5

  < Received data from server, value: 1
  < Received data from server, value: 2
  ........................................
  < Received data from server, value: 5
```

I want to modified this demo to work like this, after every single emit event to received an answer from server

```
 > EMIT event 1 from CLIENT, value: 1
 < Received data from server, value: 1

 > EMIT event 2 from CLIENT, value: 2
 < Received data from server, value: 2
```

Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did nothing wrong, you just expect a wrong thing.
You send all data at the same time

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    test2(i);
```

Thats why you see the log

```
  > EMIT event 1 from CLIENT, value: 1
  > EMIT event 2 from CLIENT, value: 2
  ..................................
  > EMIT event 5 from CLIENT, value: 5
```

Because you are not waiting to the response to send the next.

If you want to wait for the response you should write something like:

```
const socket = io();

function emit(testSent){
    console.log("FUNCTION 'emit()' test - > emit to SRV: " + testSent);
    socket.emit('emitFromClient', testSent);
}

function test2( dataSend , numberOfReplys){
    var replies=0;
    emit(dataSend)
    socket.on('feedback_emitFromClient', function (data) { // listen to news event raised by the server
        console.log("Received data from server: " + JSON.stringify(data)); //+ " || typeof: " + typeof data["result"]);                     
        if(numberOfReplys>replies){
            emit(dataSend);
            replies++;
        }
    });
}

test2(5,5);
```

server log:

```
debug -  received event (emitFromClient) from client, socket id: Js3F7F267s0P5DRAAAAN || value: 5
debug -  send data from SRV to client ->  data: 5
debug -  received event (emitFromClient) from client, socket id: Js3F7F267s0P5DRAAAAN || value: 5
debug -  send data from SRV to client ->  data: 5
debug -  received event (emitFromClient) from client, socket id: Js3F7F267s0P5DRAAAAN || value: 5
debug -  send data from SRV to client ->  data: 5
debug -  received event (emitFromClient) from client, socket id: Js3F7F267s0P5DRAAAAN || value: 5
debug -  send data from SRV to client ->  data: 5
debug -  received event (emitFromClient) from client, socket id: Js3F7F267s0P5DRAAAAN || value: 5
debug -  send data from SRV to client ->  data: 5
debug -  received event (emitFromClient) from client, socket id: Js3F7F267s0P5DRAAAAN || value: 5
debug -  send data from SRV to client ->  data: 5
```

But a better way to do this is to save a timestamp and order all the messages dependending of this date before showing them.

Synchrony is complex =)

Comment: When I call 'test2' function, which is second parameter ( times ) ?

Comment: The number of times that is going to be executed, the 5 in the for loop

Comment: Ok, I did it right! I was not sure if is that parameter or not .... but I've received same result

Comment: So you receive the desired result or not?

Comment: No! I've received same result like first time... all EMIT events are displayed first and then all data from server

Comment: I tested it and I had some errors but the logic was ok, the new code is tested and works with your server code

Comment: [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwymy59lujwy749/socketTest2-demo.zip?dl=0) is a link to entire demo project and I put there a screen shot with chrome console to see how I've received responses from server, after all EMIT events are done

Comment: You are maintaining the for loop calling the test2 function, remove it, you only have to call test2 once. Please try to understand the latest test2 function I posted, btw please don't share the code with external links that will be not available in the future.

Comment: Of course it works if I call 'test2' function once! But this is not what I'm asking for! I need to call that function in loop, at least 5 times..... so I need to triggered 5 EMIT events and received, immediately,  after each event some server response data....

Comment: The loop is inside test2 function "replies = your i" and "numberOfReplys = your 5 stop condition" with my code you are calling the emit 5 times also but not in a for loop because you have to wait for the response to send the next. If you emit all the data at the same time without waiting to the response of course you are not getting your desired result because the information takes time to go to the server and return and in that time you already executed the for...

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions! Everything it's ok!